# Extracting second word from each row in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `vendors` table in my database that am experimenting with, as shown below
[image]

And when i run the sql command below

```
SELECT vendor_name
FROM vendors
ORDER BY vendor_name
LIMIT 10
```

I get the output below
[image]

My issue is am trying to extract the second word from each `vendor_name` and when the second word doesn't exist it's supposed to return a blank cell.

And below is the sql query i have written to do just that

```
SELECT vendor_name,
       SUBSTRING(
           SUBSTRING( vendor_name, LOCATE(' ', vendor_name) + 1),
           1,
           LOCATE( ' ', SUBSTRING( vendor_name, LOCATE(' ', vendor_name) + 1) ) - 1
       ) AS second_word
FROM vendors
ORDER BY vendor_name
LIMIT 10
```

And here is the output of that sql query
[image]

If you notice from the output above, when the words in the `vendor_name` are more than two, it returns the second word just fine and when the `vendor_name` contains one word it returns a blank cell as expected.

Problem comes when the `vendor_name` contains exactly two words, instead of returning the second word it is returning a blank cell for example in the case of `American Express` and `ASC Signs`.

How can i better improve my query so that even when the `vendor_name` does contain two words, it does return the second word instead of a blank cell?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is no space after the second word, if the text ends there, the `locate()` has no space to find.

Quick hack: Add a space at the end.

```
 LOCATE( ' ', CONCAT(SUBSTRING( vendor_name, LOCATE(' ', vendor_name) + 1), ' ') ) - 1
```

Comment: i took your tips from your sql query and i came up with the solution i  needed. You can take a look at it and tell me what you think. Thank you for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT vendor_name  , substr(vendor_name , instr(vendor_name, " ") ,
 case when LOCATE (' ', vendor_name,instr(vendor_name, " ") ) > 0 then  LOCATE (' ', 
vendor_name,instr(vendor_name, " ") ) else CHAR_LENGTH (vendor_name) end )
  from vendors ;
```

Comment: i took your tips from your sql query and i came up with the solution i  needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I took tips from both @stick bit and @kiran gadhe and i came up with this sql query and it's working just fine

```
SELECT vendor_name,
       CASE
           WHEN INSTR( vendor_name, ' ' ) = 0
           THEN
               ''
           ELSE
               SUBSTRING(
                   SUBSTRING( vendor_name, LOCATE(' ', vendor_name) + 1),
                   1,
                   LOCATE( ' ', CONCAT(SUBSTRING( vendor_name, LOCATE(' ', vendor_name) + 1), ' ') ) - 1
               )
       END AS second_word
FROM vendors
ORDER BY vendor_name
LIMIT 10
```